# Gradle upgrade in Android studio

Tags: android-studio, gradle

I'm using Android Studio 4.0 (latest release) and have a project with Gradle 3.5.1. When I open the project IDE recommends to upgrade the Gradle to 4 and I accept. This upgrades the Gradle to 4.0.0.

As soon as I do this my build fails with the following error message:

A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.

> Could not create task ':app:optimizeAppDebug'.
> Unnecessarily replacing a task that does not exist is not supported.  Use create() or register() directly instead.  You attempted to replace a task named 'optimizeAppDebug', but there is no existing task with that name.

Any idea how I can fix this? I've searched for the error and people are talking about invalidating the cache and rebuilding which I've tried a few times without any luck.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. After updating the gradle I invalidated cache and restarted, then cleaned and built my project again and it worked.

I did it like this: **File -> Invalidate caches/restart -> Invalidate and Restart** when it opened again I did: **Build -> Clean Project. Build -> Rebuild Project**